# Google Map: Shown the "pinned location" before it loads the current location correctly

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to use Google Map to show my current location as shown in figure 2. However, as it takes time for Google Map to load my current location, the map first shows the location I set in the code "LatLng mPosition = new LatLng(34.6767, 33.04455);". I have tried to replace it with "LatLng mPosition;" but the same issue still exists. Any measures to correct it?

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
GetLocation getLocation = new GetLocation();    

//LatLng mPosition = new LatLng(34.6767, 33.04455);
LatLng mPosition;
final Marker marker_final = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.map);
getLocation.getLocation(getApplicationContext(), locationResult);
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)        getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
googleMap=mapFragment.getMap();
}


public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {
@Override
public void gotLocation(Location location) {
    double Longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double Latitude = location.getLatitude();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got Location Long: "+Longitude+"; Lat: "+Latitude,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mPosition = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mPosition, 13));
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18);
    googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);

    /*
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .title("Shop")
    .snippet("Is this the right location?")
    .position(mPosition)).setDraggable(true);
    */

    googleMap.addMarker(setMarkerOptions("Your Shop","The Right Position?",mPosition)).setDraggable(true);

    // map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(GmapDragActivity.this);
    googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(GmapDragActivity.this);


}
};

private MarkerOptions setMarkerOptions(String title,String msg,LatLng position){
MarkerOptions options=new MarkerOptions();  

options.title(title);
options.snippet(msg);
options.position(position);

return options;
}
```

I[image]

Comment: This is not related to the zoom level.
My current location is at the "香港仔"  (LatLng(26.2792378, 134.1776) in Hong Kong as shown in the map. 
However, when i opened the map, it first directs me the "國立中央大學" (LatLng(34.6767, 33.04455) in Taiwan and it takes ~5 seconds for it to go back to LatLng(26.2792378, 134.1776).
 I don't know why this happens and want to avoid this is quite annoying

Comment: comment this line and just verify. Just a guess.. googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, when you first load your map, you could show the last known location on your map. For that in your onCreate add this :

```
LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (mLocationManager != null) {
      Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
      LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(newLatLng, 10));

      //
      //If you want to add marker
      //
      mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLng));
}
```

Since you are already using GPS, you probably have added the necessary permissions for this code.